# GitHub API authentication for public website

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

I'm building a website that fetches data from the GitHub API, and I need to make about 100 requests per visit. Is here any way I can go over the 60 requests limit without asking for visitors to authenticate?

I've considered hard coding an access token, but maybe there's a more secure solution?

(the website is hosted on GitHub Pages)

Comment: Use your own API key to do the requests. Put the API key in a config file, make sure that config file is well protected by file permissions. Limit the API key to only what permissions are necessary. The nice thing about API keys they can be junked. Alternatively, post what you want to do and maybe we can trim down the number of requests.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not mention I'm using angular to do the requests, which means the token would be exposed anyway. Here's the repo, if you'd like to take a look: https://github.com/fabiosn/fabiosn.github.io

Comment: Please describe more about what you're doing with the Github API. The code is helpful, but I'm not going to read through all your code to figure it out.

Comment: @Schwern Basically, I'm fetching data from my profile and using it on a portfolio. I get a list of my repos, and then loop through that list to get some more data. Everything is in the dist/js/app.min.js file.

Comment: Would using JWT be acceptable? https://developer.github.com/early-access/integrations/authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I'm fetching data from my profile and using it on a portfolio. I get a list of my repos, and then loop through that list to get some more data.

Normally you'd solve that by using query caching and [Conditional Requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests) to reduce your real API calls, but that's going to be difficult in client side Javascript. Since your information is fairly static, you don't need to generate it live every single request. There's a number of ways you can cache the data, even if for a few minutes.

You could write your own little proxy server that does that querying and caching for you, perhaps with something like [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api). Then have your Javascript make a request of that server. But you might not want to run a server.

Alternatively, you can make the requests and put the results in a cache file on Github Pages. It would contain the queries, their contents, and the necessary cache information. The Javascript then uses it for making conditional requests. You can have a process which periodically updates it behind the scenes and pushes it to Github Pages. This results in live data with caching.

For example...

```
{
    "/users/fabiosn/repos": {
        "ETag": "644b5b0155e6404a9cc4bd9d8b1ae730",
        "Last-Modified": "Thu, 05 Jul 2012 15:31:30 GMT",
        "Content": [
                     {
                       "id": 79252528,
                       ...
                     }
                   ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Following your advice I was able to come with this solution: https://github.com/fabiosn/fabiosn.github.io/commit/1dbaf00241917b6c7b2c05a2e87cfacae67b8e94